# VBO colors of vertices using shaders

Tags: opengl, vbo, pyopengl

I am displaying a geometry (file format: .stl) with OpenGL (PyOpenGL and Python). Geometry data has the [form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_%28file_format%29) and is assembled from triangles.

I save to VBO data of; vertices, normals and colors. As the normal is only defined per 3 vertices (triangle) and I define color vector for every vertex, the data in VBO has the form:

```
VBO = [v1x, v1y, v1z,...vNx, vNy, vNz,
       n1x, n1y, n1z,...nNx, nNy, nNz,
       R1, G1, B1,...RN, GN, BN]
```

In words; first I save all vertices, then I "append" (use of `glBufferSubData`) all normals (number of normals is 3-times less then number of vertices and vertice's colors) and then I append color vectors of each vertex (use of `glBufferSubData`).
I would like to know if this is good idea, as I have problems painting each vertex in different color. The code for drawing is:

```
glPushMatrix()
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
glVertexPointer(3, 
                GL_FLOAT, 
                0, 
                None)
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY)
glColorPointer(3,
               GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
               0,
               self.data_size_vertices+self.data_size_normals)
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo_id)     
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,
             0,
             self.N_vertices)
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0) # reset
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY)
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
glPopMatrix()
```

I think I am having problems with `glColorPointer()`. Can someone point out the problem? I have also seen two more ways to save the data to VBO:

1. create separate VBO for vertices, VBO for normals and VBO for colors
2. one VBO but has the form: `[v1, c1, v2, c2, v3, c3, n1, ....]`

Is any of this two a better solution (more common in practice)? And do I have to assign a normal of triangle to each vertex although it is the same (for 3 vertices that define a triangle)? As I would like to get the display as shown below (left: current state, middle: plan, right: ideal - the point is the shading of surfaces), I would like to ask you to give me some directions about how to achieve this (using shaders).
[image]

Comment: What is wrong with the image you get? The "current state" is what you should get from your code (ignoring the normals, as you currently do).

Comment: @derhass OK. If I understand correctly I have to use `glNormalPointer` call to get the display similar to middle or right one? If I use `glNormalPointer`, do I have to use shaders or can this function be used without shaders and still get display like the middle or right one?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to duplicate the normal for each vertex. For OpenGL, a vertex is a set of attributes (like position, color, normal, texcoords, ...). A vertex is referenced by its index, so the i-th vertex will be composed of the i-th element of all enabled attribute arrays.

A common layout for vertex attributes is to *interleave* the attribs per vertex, like

```
v1x, v1y, v1z, n1x, n1y, n1z, R1, G1, B1, v2x, ...
```

That way, all data which is fetched for processing a single is local close to each other, increasing cache efficiency. You can use the `stride` parameter of the attrib pointers to set it up for such a layout.

The "current state" image looks to me like it should look when no normal array is enabled (and lighting still is enabled). The GL will then reuse the currently set normal vector for all vertices, resulting in the shading you see. Looking at the "ideal" image, I would conclude that the blue color is correct for the object, so I do not see what is wrong with your color array.

Comment: Ok. I will reshape the data to have the shape you advised. At the moment no normals are enabled - "current state". The difference of color of middle state is not important the focus is the shading or the drawing of the surfaces and how are they shaded. Do I have to use `glVertexAttribPointer()` function or which functions do you suggest to use? Do I have to use shaders or not to paint each vertex different color? I could not find an explicit answer about that.

Comment: @avstenit: It is hard to guess what lighing model is used when looking at the resulting image. However, It loks like the shading you show can be achieved by using the fixed-function pipeline. You just need to supply the correct normal vectors, have to set up appropriate material and light properties. However, all of this can of course be achieved by shaders, and that would be the recommenden way nowadays.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I hope I can make it using fixed-function pipeline (without shaders). I have started looking into shaders a little (it is working), but it will take time to understand the logic. As the visualisation is only one half of the project it is not the focus, the focus is on the physics part so I want to keep it simple as possible :)